# Quoting command-line arguments in shell scripts

Tags: unix, shell, wine

The following shell script takes a list of arguments, turns Unix paths into WINE/Windows paths and invokes the given executable under WINE.

```
#! /bin/sh

if [ "${1+set}" != "set" ]
then 
  echo "Usage; winewrap EXEC [ARGS...]"
  exit 1
fi

EXEC="$1"
shift

ARGS=""

for p in "$@";
do
  if [ -e "$p" ]
  then
    p=$(winepath -w $p)
  fi
  ARGS="$ARGS '$p'"
done

CMD="wine '$EXEC' $ARGS"
echo $CMD
$CMD
```

However, there's something wrong with the quotation of command-line arguments.

```
$ winewrap '/home/chris/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Microsoft Research/Z3-1.3.6/bin/z3.exe' -smt /tmp/smtlib3cee8b.smt
Executing: wine '/home/chris/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Microsoft Research/Z3-1.3.6/bin/z3.exe' '-smt' 'Z: mp\smtlib3cee8b.smt'
wine: cannot find ''/home/chris/.wine/drive_c/Program'
```

Note that:

1. The path to the executable is being chopped off at the first space, even though it is single-quoted.
2. The literal "\t" in the last path is being transformed into a tab character.

Obviously, the quotations aren't being parsed the way I intended by the shell. How can I avoid these errors?

EDIT: The "\t" is being expanded through two levels of indirection: first, `"$p"` (and/or `"$ARGS"`) is being expanded into `Z:\tmp\smtlib3cee8b.smt`; then, `\t` is being expanded into the tab character. This is (seemingly) equivalent to

```
Y='y\ty'
Z="z${Y}z"
echo $Z
```

which yields

```
zy\tyz
```

and *not*

```
zy  yz
```

UPDATE: `eval "$CMD"` does the trick. The "`\t`" problem seems to be echo's fault: "If the first operand is -n, or if any of the operands contain a backslash ( '\' ) character, the results are implementation-defined." ([POSIX specification of `echo`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you do want to have the assignment to CMD you should use

`eval $CMD`

instead of just `$CMD` in the last line of your script. This should solve your problem with spaces in the paths, I don't know what to do about the "\t" problem.

Answer (score 3):

- bash’s arrays are unportable but the only sane way to handle argument lists in shell
- The number of arguments is in ${#}
- Bad stuff will happen with your script if there are filenames starting with a dash in the current directory
- If the last line of your script just runs a program, and there are no traps on exit, you should exec it

With that in mind

```
#! /bin/bash

# push ARRAY arg1 arg2 ...
# adds arg1, arg2, ... to the end of ARRAY
function push() {
    local ARRAY_NAME="${1}"
    shift
    for ARG in "${@}"; do
        eval "${ARRAY_NAME}[\${#${ARRAY_NAME}[@]}]=\${ARG}"
    done
}

PROG="$(basename -- "${0}")"

if (( ${#} < 1 )); then
  # Error messages should state the program name and go to stderr
  echo "${PROG}: Usage: winewrap EXEC [ARGS...]" 1>&2
  exit 1
fi

EXEC=("${1}")
shift

for p in "${@}"; do
  if [ -e "${p}" ]; then
    p="$(winepath -w -- "${p}")"
  fi
  push EXEC "${p}"
done

exec "${EXEC[@]}"
```

Comment: Define "unportable". I don't mind requiring /bin/bash instead of /bin/sh, but I"m hesitant to require a recent version. Has someone put together a Unix shell script portability matrix (i.e., which features are available in which versions of which shells on which platforms)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try preceeding the spaces with \ like so:

```
/home/chris/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Microsoft\ Research/Z3-1.3.6/bin/z3.exe
```

You can also do the same with your \t problem - replace it with \\t.

Comment: Both of the paths are perfectly valid Unix paths *as input to the script*. The single quotes should eliminate the need for escaping spaces. And the "\t" is automatically generated by the `winepath` command (it turns "/tmp" into "Z:\tmp").

Answer (score 0):

replace the last line from $CMD to just

wine '$EXEC' $ARGS

You'll note that the error is ''/home/chris/.wine/drive_c/Program' and not '/home/chris/.wine/drive_c/Program'

The single quotes are not being interpolated properly, and the string is being split by spaces.